# Application Insights Database Dependency Command Invalid

Tags: c#, sitefinity, azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insights on a web application and it is logging SQL dependencies, but the command listed is not a valid SQL command (AFAICT).

The WebApp is targeting .net 4.6.1 and I'm using [Application Insights for Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web) version 2.1.0.  It is collecting data points no problem, but the database dependencies are crazy.

The Command is shown as 'Server | Database'.  Here is a copy paste of the Dependency Properties screen.

```
Dependency Properties
Event time         7/26/2016, 3:08:05 PM
Dependency type    SQL
Successful call    true
Result code        <empty>
Duration           1.66 ms

Command
my-db-servername | my-db-name

Related Items
Request in which this dependency call was made    1
Failed or slow calls to remote dependencies       1
All available telemetry for this operation        2
All available telemetry 5 minutes before and after this event    507
```

When I try to apply this 'command' using SSMS > new query, it says it is invalid.

We are using Sitefinity for part of the application and it is making 100s to 1000s of calls to the database, each lasting < 1 ms (~500us) and listing the above command as the database command.

At this point I'm not sure whether it is an app insights thing, a sitefinity thing, or something else all together.

However, I'm really interested in why that command is listed as such.

Answer (score 1):

Application Insights command is not a command text. It is concatenated from multiple parameters like this:

1. If you run stored procedures (4.6+ or (4.0+ StatusMonitor)): server name , pipe, database name, pipe, SPROC name.
2. If you use StatusMonitor and you run command text: server name , pipe, database name, pipe, command text
3. If you do not use StatusMontior but have 4.6+ and you run command text: server name , pipe, database name.

I assume your case is 3.

Comment: Should I install Status Monitor on the web server of the database server?

Comment: StatusMonitor should be installed on the box that you monitor is running. It installs profiler that is attached on application start.

Comment: To clarify, at the moment we have case nr 3. What exactly should I do to see the sql queries in the command text?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to write "box where app is running", not "monitor". You need to login to the box where your application is deployed, install StatusMonitor and restart IIS.